# printf printing all strings to output

Tags: c, linux, unix, pipe, dup

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(){
    int fd[2];
    int old = dup(1);
    char buf[10];
    pipe(fd);       
    dup2(fd[1],1);
    printf("Don't Print!\n");
    dup2(old,1);
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0; 
}
```

In the above C code "Don't Print" also gets printed.

> dup2(fd[1],1)

Sets the default output to the pipe. So printf should write to the output which in this case is the pipe.

> dup2(old,1)

if remove this then nothing is printed to the screen but when I include it both strings are printed to the screen. Can someone point out the mistake in my code.

Comment: The behavior seems to be related to output buffering. If you put `fflush(stdout);` after `printf("Don't print!\n");`, then the program will only print out `"Hello world!"` when you leave in the `dup2(old,1)`.

Comment: @lurker but wouldn't terminating `\n` cause implicit flush for the first `printf()`?

Comment: @lurker Thank you so much. when we say file descriptor =  1 does it point to the same thing as stdout? stdout is a file pointer so do they point to the same file or have I misunderstood, using fflush(stdout) has solved the problem if you write the answer I can mark it as solved.

Comment: @Sergio that's what I would expect, but there still seems to be a buffering phenomenon going on here, since `fflush(stdout)` changes the behavior. I don't have an explanation. Thus my use of the word *seems* in my original comment.

Comment: @AAB, yes, the file descriptor for 1 corresponds to standard output. I stopped short of making it an actual answer since I can't, at the moment, explain it. It's currently just an observation.